# PHP: return value from function and echo it directly?

Tags: php, function, echo

this might be a stupid question but …

**php**

```
function get_info() {
    $something = "test";
    return $something;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="test"><?php echo get_info(); ?></div>
```

Is there a way to make the function automatically "echo" or "print" the returned statement?
Like I wanna do this …

```
<div class="test"><?php get_info(); ?></div>
```

… without the "echo" in it?

Any ideas on that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the special tags:

```
<?= get_info(); ?>
```

Or, of course, you can have your function echo the value:

```
function get_info() {
    $something = "test";
    echo $something;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why return when you can echo if you need to?

```
function 
get_info() {
    $something = "test";
    echo $something;
}
```

Comment: May be he don't want to echo each time he use this function.

Comment: Maybe want to echo the returned value in some other function.

Answer (score 3):

Why not wrap it?

```
function echo_get_info() {
  echo get_info();
}
```

and

```
<div class="test"><?php echo_get_info(); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have the function echo the value out itself.

```
function get_info() {
    $something = "test";
    echo $something;
    return $something;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One visit to [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)'s Manual page would have yielded you the answer, which is indeed what the previous answers mention: the **shortcut syntax**.

Be very careful though, if [`short_open_tag`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) is disabled in `php.ini`, shortcutting echo's won't work, and your code will be output in the HTML. (e.g. when you move your code to a different server which has a different configuration).

For the reduced portability of your code I'd advise against using it.

Comment: For the record, as of php 5.4, "<?= is now always available, regardless of the short_open_tag php.ini option."  See http://us1.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

Either print it directly in the function:

```
function get_info() {
    $something = "test";
    echo $something;
}
```

Or use the PHP's shorthand for echoing:

```
<?= get_info(); ?>
```

Though I recommend you keep the echo. It's more readable and easier to maintain returning functions, and the shorthands are not recommended for use.

Answer (score 0):

You could add it as a parameter so that you can echo or return depending on the situation. Set it to true or false depending on what you would use most.

```
<?php
function get_info($echo = true) {

    $something = "test";

    if ($echo) {
        echo $something;
    } else {
        return $something;
    }

}

?>

<?php get_info(); ?>
<?php echo get_info(false); ?>
```