# Echo from function php

Tags: php

hello i want to echo a result from functions

code

```
function AboutUser()
{
    global $Connection;

    $GetUsers = mysqli_query($Connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='GentritAbazi'");
    while($Show_Users = mysqli_fetch_array($GetUsers))
    {
        return $SignupDate = $Show_Users['signup_date'];
        $Email = $Show_Users['email'];
        $Gender = $Show_Users['gender'];
        $Country = $Show_Users['country'];
    }
}
```

Now my code not work

```
AboutUser()
```

how to do this ?

Comment: How are you calling the AboutUser() function? This is only the declaration

Comment: StackOverflow does not offer clairvoyance services. It could be helpful if you describe the error, add any error messages that are output and what you did to make it go. Also, your code does not contain any `echo` statement.

Comment: Maybe if you added an `echo`...

Comment: Where did you learn how to use the `return` keyword ?

Comment: Express more clearly what you do mean by "not work": What is the expected bahavior and what is the seen behavior. More, pay attention to the orsed of your statements: all the statements in a block after a `return` will not be executed...

Comment: You need to have a semi-colon at the end of the line when you call the function. It's missing from the example code you provided.

Comment: after "return" is used everything else is ignored please learn when and how to use return

Answer (score 0):

Because you `return $SignupDate = $Show_Users['signup_date'];`

You want to echo, not return.

Let's use this in the while loop.

```
echo $Show_Users['signup_date'] ."<br>";
echo $Show_Users['email']  ."<br>";
echo $Show_Users['gender']  ."<br>";
echo $Show_Users['country'] ."<br>";
echo '<hr>'
```

But that is most elegant, if you collect all the data into a big array, and loop through that array.

```
return mysqli_fetch_all($GetUsers);
```

Based on the comments, and after I realized, you probably want to get one users data, here is the updated code:

```
function AboutUser($userName) {
    global $Connection;
    $res = mysqli_query($Connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".  mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection, $userName)."'");
    return mysqli_fetch_row($res);
}

$userData = AboutUser('GentritAbazi');
if (!empty($userData)) {
    echo $userData['signup_date'] ."<br>";
    echo $userData['email']  ."<br>";
    echo $userData['gender']  ."<br>";
    echo $userData['country'] ."<br>";
}
```

Comment: _But that is most elegant, if you collect all the data into a big array, and loop through that array._ Nope, avoid it at any chance if you do not need it. But use if it makes sense, eg for sorting, pagination and the like.

Comment: In a web app, in most cases you use MVC, so you can collect data, and pass the array to your view. This is why I sad, it is most elegant.

Comment: why use 5 lines to fetch instead of just `mysqli_fetch_all` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function AboutUser()
{
    global $Connection;

    $GetUsers = mysqli_query($Connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='GentritAbazi'");
    while($Show_Users = mysqli_fetch_array($GetUsers))
    {
        echo $Show_Users['signup_date'];
        echo $Show_Users['email'];
        echo $Show_Users['gender'];
        echo $Show_Users['country'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have the function echo the value instead of returning it, like mentioned above.

Or you can use special tags e.g.

```
<?= 
AboutUser(); 
?>
```

Hopefully this works

Comment: Why do you answer if you cannot proof your code works?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020575/php-return-value-from-function-and-echo-it-directly