# how works or operator in if statements and print

Tags: php

I have two questions

1) how can i make php to check getnext() function,if it exists or what value it has ???

```
$a = 1;
if($a == 1 or getnext()== 1){
    echo "yeap";                 //this works
}
```

2)i want to write condition -- if $a or $b is equal to 1 , print the variable name that has the value of 1.

Is it possible to do in php ??can i do it this way???

```
if($a ==1 or $b==1){
    print($a or $b);    
}
```

thanks in advance:)

Comment: I can't really answer your `getnext()` as there is no function showing for it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example do as follows :

```
if($a ==1 || $b==1){
   print (($a == 1)? $a : $b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question,

your `getnext()` function must be **return** some valid integer value then only you can compare it with integer 1.

for second,
You should write

```
if($a == 1 && $b == 1){
    echo 'both are 1';
}
else if($a == 1){
    echo '$a is 1';
}
else if($b == 1){
    echo '$b is 1';
}else{
    // both are not 1
}
```

also see this links,
[logical operators or vs || (double pipe) in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710924/logical-operators-or-vs-double-pipe-in-php)

[PHP: return value from function and echo it directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020575/php-return-value-from-function-and-echo-it-directly)

Answer (score 0):

You write condition? You use if and else, if no else in if you put return. Goodluck